# How to make the PDE target definition editor show all plug-ins?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, nexus, tycho, eclipse-pde, p2

We aim at using Tycho+Eclipse PDE to build OSGi bundles in a distributed team.

So far artifacts are built and deployed to a Nexus OSS repository. This has been 
augmented with [p2 support](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Nexus/Nexus+OSGi+Experimental+Features+-+P2+Repository+Plugin), "artifacts.xml" and "content.xml" are generated 
(or supplied by Tycho) and correctly resolved by Tycho and the [p2 Browser](https://github.com/ifedorenko/p2-browser).

The missing link is to add the resultant p2 bundle repository to the target platform 
definition used by PDE. The PDE target editor apparently only [supports features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18341689/1018191) 
or ["categorized" plugins](http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2010/11/26/creating-a-p2-repository-from-features-and-plugins/), no plain bundles.

Tycho's repository plugin and feature-packaging of bundles independently developed by 
different partners appears too cumbersome to synchronize. We'd like to adhere to simple
Maven/OBR-like sharing of bundles via a single repository.

Is there a way to enhance the bundle's or repository's p2 metadata in terms of a 
generic category as suggested in [this blog](http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2010/11/26/creating-a-p2-repository-from-features-and-plugins/), e.g. either via the "tycho-p2-publisher:publish-categories" goal or by configuring/extending the "Nexus p2 Repository Plugin" to make them accessible to the PDE UI ?

This questions seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142983/tycho-categorize-p2-metadat), with a hint that support for the "iu" syntax is not implemented yet.

Comment: PDE can only see root IUs.  Features and categorized items get treated as root IUs, but it should be possible to mark other IUs as being root.  http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/FAQ#How_can_I_determine_what_is_a_root_IU.3F

Comment: The indicated page and other sources are quite cryptical about the "root UIs". In our case we build and provision plain bundles via Maven/Tycho. What does it mean in concrete words to "explicitly provision" an installable unit in order to become a "root UI" (and thus become visible for PDE) ?

Comment: The p2 metadata (content.xml) determines whether an IU is a Root IU.  How to set up the correct p2 metadata during the Maven/Tycho build is outside my knowledge base.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try another target editor. There exists a alternative [TPD editor/generator](https://github.com/mbarbero/fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform/) from Mikaël Barbero with some useful features:

- autocomplition
- version management
- mergeable structure
- ...